# How to perform verification processes for EV ssl certification

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, openssl, ssl-certificate, bluehost

I recently purchased EV ssl certificate from comodosslstore.com for my site, which is hosted on GCP and purchased domain from bluehost but now i'm getting some issues to verifying my identity and getting troubles in verification process for my ssl certificate.
So, someone can please tell me what exactly i should do for this verification process, like what should I do as a individual person. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to follow the rules set by Comodo. The best place is to ask them.

Their job is to provide with reasonable certainty that you are who you say you are.

I have been thru this process many times. They want to see a published phone number in your name that they can verify using public resources. For US companies a Dunn&Bradstreet verification, business license, articles of incorporation, etc.

Comodo will decide which methods that they will use to verify you.

If you are purchasing an SSL certificate as an "individual" you will have difficultly. An EV SSL Certificate means "Extended Validation". Comodo will make a serious effort to verify you and your business and if they cannot, they will not approve your certificate. If you are not a registered business, I wish you luck obtaining one.

If you are not a company, you are a high risk for financial transactions. My advise is to switch and just use a DV SSL Certificate. This is cheaper, requires fewer verification steps and is much easier to obtain. I also recommend to most companies that are not processing financial transactions (credit cards) to use Let's Encrypt. Move your shopping cart to a vendor such as Shopify so that you are not involved in transactions. PCI compliance is difficult and expensive.

Answer (score 2):

**7-Stage Authentication For EV SSL Certificates**

1. The EV Enrollment Form
2. Organization Authentication
3. Operational Existence
4. Physical Address
5. Telephone Verification
6. Domain Authentication
7. Final Verification Call

Remember,  Whole validation process for EV SSL certificates can take up to a week.
You can get it in deep from this [article](https://comodosslstore.com/ssl-validation-process/ev).